# Digit OCR using Tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to ocr some numbers:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And I have made this code to test different psm arguments (6,7,8,13), I don't see much difference.

```
import os
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
    r"path/to/tesseract"
)
def apply_tesseract(image_path, psm):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=f"--psm {psm} digits")
    return image, text

def display_images_with_text(images, texts):
    num_images = len(images)
    num_rows = min(3, num_images)
    num_cols = (num_images + num_rows - 1) // num_rows

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, figsize=(12, 8), subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})
    
    for i, (image, text) in enumerate(zip(images, texts)):
        ax = axes[i // num_cols, i % num_cols] if num_rows > 1 else axes[i % num_cols]
        ax.imshow(image)
        ax.axis("off")
        ax.set_title(text)

    plt.show()

def main(folder_path):
    for psm in [6]:
        images = []
        texts = []
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            if filename.lower().endswith((".png")):
                image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                image, text = apply_tesseract(image_path, psm)
                images.append(image)
                texts.append(text)
        display_images_with_text(images, texts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = r"./digitImages"
    main(folder_path)
```

This is the output of `--psm 6`

[image]

As you can see, it's not that good.

How can I improve this? the number images are already black and white and quite small, I've tried some processing but I end up with the same black and white image.

```
# Read the original image
original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)

new_width = original_image.shape[1] * 2  # Double the width
new_height = original_image.shape[0] * 2  # Double the height
resized_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (new_width, new_height))


# Convert the original image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Sharpen the blurred image
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 9, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)

# Apply Otsu's thresholding to the blurred image
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Update:

Turns out simply adding some borders helped a ton, nto perfect but better.

[image]

Comment: My code works PARTIALLY though...

Comment: Ah, yeah I want to improve the character recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem statement: Trying to OCR brief sequences of 2 or 3 digits yields sub-par recognition performance.

Solution summary: Beginning each digit sequence with a short preamble that is "easy" to OCR gives Tesseract a hint about font size and will improve recognition performance.

```py
def apply_tesseract(image_path: Path, psm: int) -> tuple[np.ndarray, str]:
    image = cv2.imread(f"{image_path}")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    assert np.max(image) <= 255
    h, w = image.shape
    both = np.concatenate((_get_hello(h), image), axis=1)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(both, config=f"--psm {psm} digits")
    return both, text


def _get_hello(height: int, word: str = "Hello"):
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    bottom_left = 6, height - 3
    font_scale = 1.35
    font_color = (0, 0, 0)
    thickness = 1
    line_type = cv2.LINE_AA

    img = 255 * np.ones((height, 70), dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(
        img, word, bottom_left, font, font_scale, font_color, thickness, line_type
    )
    return img
```

This yields zero errors with PSM set to either 6 or 7,
on the example number images you supplied.

BTW, one can obtain much the same effect by simply
catenating those number images.
This produces a "986368798212196" recognition result.

(I was going to try to recognize e.g. "Hello 212 world",
but stopped when it turned out that a preamble suffices.)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this library for my project and  completed the POC but this is not accurate sometimes it will give some random data then your logic will fail.

if you are earning something by the project where you are implementing then you should go with image processing google api's or some other service for scanning and getting the accurate result. but that will come with the cost.